# export group of charts to image

Tags: excel, vba

Based on [this old SE answer][1] I have the code at bottom of this post working to group 2 charts and export them to a single `PNG` file.

**However**, the loop will bomb out a random intervals.  It may save 5 images, it may save 19.  But it always bombs out with this error message and `myShp.CopyPicture` highlighted in yellow in the code editor.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
Sub test()
For k = 0 To 128
 Dim chtObj As ChartObject
 Dim myShp As Shape
 Set myShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 7", "Chart 1")).Group
 myShp .CopyPicture
 Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(myShp.Left, myShp.Top, MyChartsShape.Width, myShp.Height)
 chtObj.Activate
 chtObj.Chart.Paste
 chtObj.Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Pic" & k & ".png", Filtername:="PNG"
 chtObj.Delete
 Set chtObj = Nothing
 myShp.Ungroup
 Set myShp = Nothing
 'placeholder for code here that changes chart data
 Next k
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:  If i remove the code that changes the charts it, the code runs fine through entire loop.  I've tried adding `DoEvents` as I assume the chart must not be finished updating before i'm trying to export it.  Not helping...
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761350/6794745
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEFUM.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but doubt it is best solution. I'll show it here as an unaccepted answer until clean one comes along...

After the code that updates the charts (`placeholder for code here that changes chart data`) I added these lines.

```
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.Refresh
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Refresh
 DoEvents
 Sleep (50)
```

The code runs for a bit and I see images showing up in File Explorer - then it stops for 2-4 seconds, and starts back up.  Not sure what is happening there, but the above code cleared it up.