# How to send email with shapes as a image in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a*.xls file which contains a plugin generated shapes which forms a chart.
How can I send those shapes as an image acompany with some text in a email using VBA?
I know how to get the shapes in VBA, but don't know how to convert them into a single image.

FYI: I can not install any software or programming environment on my working computer. MS Office is only what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel Vba has a [CopyPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841052.aspx) Method on the chart object that you can use to copy a chart to the clipboard and then paste to the image into a new email.  I will post a quick demo when I get the chance, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.  Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687353/29467) as it may help as well.

**EDIT**
Found that you can also Export a chart as an image.
Try this, I have tested this and it does work.

```
Sub SendMail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = Me.ChartObjects(1)
    Dim myFilename  As String

    myFilename = "c:\temp\test.png"

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill myFilename
    On Error GoTo 0

    myChart.chart.Export myFilename, "PNG"


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hello World!"
        .Attachments.Add myFilename
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```